# How to make space between items using d-flex

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I still do not know where I should separate my items by grid system and col and when to use d-flex? Imagine I have 4 buttons:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn">First</button>
  <button class="btn">second</button>
  <button class="btn">Third</button>
  <button class="btn">fourth</button>
  <button class="btn">Fifth</button>
  <button class="btn">six</button>
</div>
```

I have items in row and center but without padding out space among them, how can I achieve it? And should I use col and row or flex?

[image: myproblem]

Comment: have you try to add margin class from bootstrap?

Comment: @Sfili_81 where should i give margin?

Comment: add `mx-1` to all the button elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif please see the image in my question,mx-1 does not work

Comment: try mx-2 or mx-3, etc you have the choice

Comment: @TemaniAfif in cases like this it would be better to use grid system and row?

Comment: @ilmagnifico: you should look into form-horizontal

Answer (score 12):

In Bootstrap 5, There is an option to use gap. Using the gap you can provide space between flex items. I was also struggling with the same issue and i don't wanted to use margin or padding. So gap is the best solution for me.

```css
.d-flex{
  gap:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn">First</button>
  <button class="btn">second</button>
  <button class="btn">Third</button>
  <button class="btn">fourth</button>
  <button class="btn">Fifth</button>
  <button class="btn">six</button>
</div>
```

Comment: gap works best, there are utility classes in bs5. so no need to modify d-flex see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#gap

Comment: @marc.d you are right. Either we can use the utility class or can give it using css.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you need to migrate to Bootstrap 5 and use the gap spacing utility.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center gap-3">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">First</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">second</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Third</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">fourth</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Fifth</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">six</button>
</div>
```

Take a look on: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#gap

Also: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<div class="d-flex" style="gap: 10px">
    Content
</div>
```

It should work with any BS version.

Also, in CSS-Tricks website we read:

> The gap property in CSS is a shorthand for row-gap and column-gap ,
> specifying the size of gutters, which is the space between rows and
> columns within grid, flex, and multi-column layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `justify-content: center`, have a look at its other values:

`justify-content: space-around`, `justify-content: space-evenly`, `justify-content: space-between`.

They provide spacing between elements and should help.

Comment: that put a big space between items

Comment: @ilmagnifico In this case, if you want a fixed amount of space, consider adding a fixed or dynamic (vw, %) padding or margin (whatever fits you better) on each button. Remember that margin goes outside element's border, while padding stays inside.

Comment: i gave it padding but it gives the padding around whole d-flex and not item by item

Answer (score 1):

```css
.d-flex {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between" >
<button class="btn">First</button>
<button class="btn">second</button>
<button class="btn">Third</button>
<button class="btn">fourth</button>
<button class="btn">Fifth</button>
 <button class="btn">six</button>
</div>

<br>
OR
<br>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-around" >
<button class="btn">First</button>
<button class="btn">second</button>
<button class="btn">Third</button>
<button class="btn">fourth</button>
<button class="btn">Fifth</button>
 <button class="btn">six</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you are using bootstrap you need to add class.

Comment: d-flex is a class of Bootstrap, it is a class for `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: how do you adjust this space?

Comment: Using justify-content: space-between, but it is a class for that property on bootstrap, check the documentation about flex helpers

Comment: Please have a look at this link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: @IshitaRay How to add gap to d-flex?